# Android Listview item selection in Xamarin using VS 2012 C#

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using VS 2012 working on Android app. Actually, I want to achieve this:

```
// lv = My listView Name. 
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{ 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) 
    {      
        String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
    }
});
```

But, I'm not getting **setOnItemClickListener()** Event. Reason is, I'm working in C# using **Xamarin**. I want to get select value or item of **ListView**. How I can do this?

Comment: don't  forget to mark the right answer that helps you

Answer (score 13):

Have your activity implement ListView.IOnItemClickListener like this:

```
public class SomeActivity: Activity, ListView.IOnItemClickListener
```

Get a refence to your listview like this:

```
LsitView LV = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.id_in_axml);
```

Then set the OnItemClickListner to the activity since we are going to implement the interface ListView.IOnItemClickListener

```
lstItems.OnItemClickListener = this;
```

Finally add this to your activity class:

```
public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
//whatever you need it to do goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the complete code snippet:

```
    private List<String>namess;
    private ListView listvieww;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        listvieww = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);


        namess = new List<String>();

        namess.Add("Security Solution");
        namess.Add("software");
        namess.Add("hardware");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,namess);

        listvieww.Adapter = adapter;
        //listvieww.ItemClick += listView_ItemClick;


        listvieww.ItemClick += (object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            string selectedFromList = listvieww.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).ToString();

            Console.WriteLine( selectedFromList);
        };

    }
```

Comment: I came up with something similar for the ItemClick even but I can't understand what it's not working in my case... can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491960/how-to-retrieve-the-row-content-of-a-listview-item-when-user-clicks-on-it Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use ItemClick and a delegate for put your event code, like this:

```
lv.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}
```