# How to get the data of a ListView item the user has clicked on with listview.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position)?

Tags: java, c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

in a Xamarin.Android app, I have a ListView which I previously populated. 
In the listview_ItemClick event handler, which correctly fires, I would like to retrieve the text of the clicked listview-item views, in order to show some info about it in a AlertDialog.

My code is not working because all I can get to is a Java.Lang.Object (lvItem) and I don't know how to extract from it the Views I need.

```
private void lv_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {

    lvItem = lv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
    // lvItem is a Java.Lang.Object

    Toast.MakeText(this,  + "you clicked" + lvItem, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

If I run it like this, the Toast prints:

> you clicked System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,
>   System.String]

Note that each ListView row is made up of two TextViews, and I populate the ListView by passing a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` to the ListView Adapter constructor.

To put it simpler:

LISTVIEW

| textView1 | textView2 |   ---> item 1

| textView1 | textView2 |   ---> item 2

If user clicks on item2 of ListView I need to retrieve textView1.Text or textView2.Text of item 2.

I also thought about doing:

```
FindViewById<TextView>(resultsListView.GetItemIdAtPosition(e.Position);
```

but the Adapter GetItemIdAtPosition returns a long instead of a int, and so I am not sure that it's the same kind of Id.

The following is not working too (I think it's the same of `lv.GetItemAtPosition(e.position)`:

```
lv.Adapter.GetItem(e.Position);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with something like this?

```
lvItem = lv.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
```

Although im not sure it will work with java objects, maybe try to cast this object with the help of this thread? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7894/how-to-convert-a-type-to-java-lang-object

Converting **Java.Lang.Object** to **C#**:

```
public static class ObjectTypeHelper
{
    public static T Cast<T>(this Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : class
    {
        var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You only need the first line to get the Java Object for the textview data. The thread you linked is about converting a C# type to a Java Object, but in it I could also find code to convert back from a Java Object to a C# Object. I could post the exact part of the code for that as my own answer, but since I'd like to mark your answer as correct for pointing me to the right solution, I think it would be better if you could refactor your answer to specifically mention the Java to C# conversion code. If you don't want to, just tell me, and with your permission I'll post it as my answer.

Comment: glab my post helped you :) , i have edit my answer, is this enough? what do you think?

Comment: Sure, I think you could just remove this line `var text = ((TextView)lvItem.GetChildAt(1)).Text;` which can be a little confusing and is not needed because what you will feed to the converter class is just `lvItem`. Marking your answer as correct now, good job :)

Answer (score 0):

try this it might help

```
void OnListItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
var listView = sender as ListView;
var t = tableItems[e.Position];
Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t.Heading,   
Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can get the data from the underlying data structure directly, but I don't like having to expose the data structure globally on the activity class and instead I'd like to just get the data by going through the event handler parameter (e) for the clicked listview item. @CDrosos helped me getting it right, check his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> lstItems;
```

**lstItems** contains all the list item, which is loaded in the listview. From the listView click listener you will get the position of the selected item. Suppose it is **i**. Then you can take that item from **lstItems**.

```
private void lv_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {

    Dictionary<string,string> selectedItem=lstItems.get(e.Position);
    // toast necessary information using selectedItem object

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can get the data from the underlying data structure directly, but I don't like having to expose the data structure globally on the activity class and instead I'd like to just get the data by going through the event handler parameter (e) for the clicked listview item. @CDrosos helped me getting it right, check his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Button that catch the Ítem Clicked...

You can have the element Position like this.

> int position= FindViewById(Resource.Id.listIncindentes).CheckedItemPosition;

And the element value like this.

> var value= FindViewById(Resource.Id.listIncindentes).GetItemAtPosition(position);

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do something like this `((TextView)e.View).getText().toString()`

Comment: I did: ((TextView)e.View).Text.ToString() but I got the error message "Invalid Cast".

Answer (score -1):

Check the below code for use the Particular Textview and other view from Listview Items.

Like :

TextView mTextView = (TextView) listview.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.text);

You can easily get the list item of Listview.

Comment: It makes no difference to call `.FindViewById()` on `listview.getChildAt(0)` rather that just calling it on any other view or within the Activity with just `FindViewById(view.id)` so what you are doing is basically just retrieving the built-in Android.Resource.Id.Text1 (or `R.id.text1` in Java), which, in case you are using them in the listview adapter, will be used by the adapter to store the element of the listview that **is currently visibile on screen**, not the clicked one.